# Animação para diminuir o tamanho de um cubo no Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, for

Olá!
Estou no Unity usando C# e tenho um cubo que, quando eu aperto 'q', ele diminui pra 0.5 de escala partindo da escala 1 e quando eu solto o 'q', ele volta para a escala 1. Queria que houvesse alguma rápida animação do decrescimento e crescimento do cubo e pensei em fazer um For pra isso, estou certo? Há alguma função específica para isso?

Comment: inclua o seu código à pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa o DOtween:
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/dotween-hotween-v2-27676

```
int duracao = 5;
    private void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            gameObject.transform.DOScale( new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), duracao);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            gameObject.transform.DOScale(new Vector3(1, 1, 1), duracao);
        }
    }
```